How can i keep the authentication state when dealing with Microsoft Graph API SDK and blazor in InteractiveAuto mode?
my application use Microsoft Graph SDK (Microsoft.Graph) and Blazor on .net 9.
The authentication is currently setup to use the Microsoft Authentication on the server side like this:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

My application authentication work when rendered on the server side but not when the state switch to the webassembly mode (client side).
I have try many things, but i cant find the right way to make it work.
I know the authentication state do not persist when the render state change, but i dont know what to change to make this work.
In the first, i had try to use the basic authentication with identity then use the Microsoft Graph OpenId to get the token and manage it myself but again, i did not find all information on how to do it.
I have found this documentation that give some information, but i dont know what's the best way...
Do someone can point me to the right dirrection?
Thanks!

I found the problem. I need to add AddAuthenticationStateSerialization() and a state provider on the server program.cs .
Like this:
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents()
    .AddAuthenticationStateSerialization();

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

the IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
internal sealed class IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider(
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
    IOptions<IdentityOptions> options)
: RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider(loggerFactory)
{
    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
        await using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
    }

    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (user is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(options.Value.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }
}

and on the client program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthenticationStateDeserialization();

